# How to apply a background color to TextElements of a TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

Is it possible to apply a background color to the inline text of a TextBlock instead of the entire rectangular bounds of the TextBlock? In other words, I would like to have this:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <!-- No such "Background" property -->
    <Span Background="Red">
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

(Just like `<span style="background-color: red">` in HTML)

Instead of this:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<Border Background="Red">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Is this even supported? I've been looking through the documentation for the TextBlock and RichTextBlock classes but I can't see any way of setting the background of the inline text. I think WPF supports this.

---

EDIT

I should mention, I need this to work with automatically wrapped text. I don't know how many lines there will be, or else I could just manually use a Border for each line of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is not currently supported in UWP apps.

WPF has a `Background` property for `Run` elements, which can be used inside `TextBlock`, but `UWP`'s `Run` does not support this.

The only way I can think of to implement this would be using HTML and a `WebView`, or somehow using `Win2D` rendering, both of which are quite cumbersome solutions...